# How to pass context to anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, callback

There are some function, thats do something long work and its provides callback.

```
someFunc: function(argument, callback, context) {
  // do something long

  // call callback function
  callback(context);
}
```

In application I use this function

```
someFunc('bla-bla', function (context) {
  // do something with this scope
  context.anotherFunc();
}, this);
```

How to implement callback function without passing `context` parameter?

Need some like this:

```
someFunc('bla-bla', function () {
  // do something with this scope
  this.anotherFunc();
}, this);
```

Comment: So in your final example it appears you are passing the context (to something at least) are you just curious on how to reference the argument if it isn't named?

Comment: You are passing the parameter, you're just not using it. And I don't understand why.

Comment: @bfavaretto: OP is using it by passing it into the callback so that the callback can take advantage of the methods of the outer `this` value. So the question is how to achieve the last code block... getting the proper `this` in the callback so it doesn't need to be passed as an argument.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The accepted answer seems somewhat outdated. Assuming you're operating on a relatively modern browser, you can use `Function.prototype.bind` in [vanilla javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Alternatively, if you are using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), you can use `_.bind` or `$.proxy` respectively (which will fallback to `call`/`apply` if necessary).

Here is a simple demonstration of these three options:

```
// simple function that takes another function
// as its parameter and then executes it.
function execute_param(func) {
    func();
}

// dummy object. providing an alternative context.
obj = {};
obj.data = 10;

// no context provided
// outputs 'Window'
execute_param(function(){
    console.log(this);
});

// context provided by js - Function.prototype.bind
// src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
// outputs 'Object { data=10 }''
execute_param(function(){
    console.log(this);
}.bind(obj));

// context provided by underscore - _.bind
// src: http://underscorejs.org/#bind
// outputs 'Object { data=10 }'
execute_param(_.bind(function(){
    console.log(this);
},obj));

// context provided by jQuery - $.proxy
// src: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/
// outputs 'Object { data=10 }'
execute_param($.proxy(function(){
    console.log(this);
},obj));
```

You can find the code in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yMm6t/1/ (*note: ensure that the developer console is open, or you won't see any output*)

Comment: Yes. Now I'm using underscore everywhere :)

Comment: @PiONeeR Yeah, me too :) You might want to reconsider what should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How do you bind `this` under another variable name? Like `.bind(that)`?

Answer (score 15):

Use `Function.prototype.call` to invoke a function and manually set the `this` value of that function.

```
someFunc: function(argument, callback, context) {
    callback.call(context); // call the callback and manually set the 'this'
}
```

Now your callback has the expected `this` value.

```
someFunc('bla-bla', function () {
  // now 'this' is what you'd expect
    this.anotherFunc();
}, this);
```

---

Of course you can pass arguments like normal in the `.call` invocation.

```
callback.call(context, argument);
```